# Does Packet tracer 5.3 support defining a network as "non-broadcast"?

Tags: networking

I'm trying to define a network as a non-broadcast ... but looks like packet tracer doesn't support this type of networks.. though it does support "broadcast" and "point-to-point"
Does this have anything to do with the version of packet tracer I'm using (5.3)?

and if yes... is there some other way to define a network as non-broadcast?

Answer (score 0):

After testing and searching.. the answer is no. The only version that supports "non-broadcast" command is 5.0
The newer versions of cisco packet tracer only support defining networks as "point-to-point" or "broadcast". Though, non have the same characteristics.